# Controlling two joints simultaneously

Tags: ros, action, gripper, grasping, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the Kuka Youbot arm (http://www.youbot-store.com/youbot-store/youbots/youbots/kuka-youbot-5-degree-of-freedom-arm-with-2-finger-gripper). When running the youbot_driver, several topics are created including a topic called "arm_1/gripper_controller/position_command" which takes the message type "brics_actuator/JointPositions." However, the gripper consists of two separate joints: one for the left finger, and one for the right finger. If I try to input a command using rostopic pub, I will have to specify which finger I want to move, either "gripper_finger_joint_l" or "gripper_finger_joint_r." This is a problem because i want the gripper to open or close by moving both fingers simultaneously. How can I do this? At first, I thought that I would try to add a "mimic" tag in the URDF but apparently this is no longer supported. What other options do I have for controlling both gripper joints at the same time?

My ultimate goal is to create an action server that takes something like "control_msgs/GripperCommandAction" with the opening width specified, and it will just open or close to that width.

Thank you,
-Adrian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187890/controlling-two-joints-simultaneously/) by [clarkeaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19625/clarkeaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message `brics_actuator/JointPositions` has:

```
brics_actuator/JointValue[] positions
```

This is a list of JointValue variables.

This means you can 'push back' the values for two joints and you will get both joints moving.
JointValue looks like this:

```
time timeStamp
string joint_uri
string unit
float64 value
```

Create two separate JointValue variables and fill them up with the stuff for both joints.
Create a 'goal' message with JointPositions.
Then, push them unto goal.positions.

```
goal.positions.push_back(first_finger_value);
goal.positions.push_back(second_finger_value);
```

I hope that helps.
Have a great day ahead!

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clarkeaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19625/clarkeaa/) on 2014-07-26**:
Thanks for the response. However I am not sure what you mean by "push back." So I would create something like: first_finger = timeStamp1, joint_uri1, unit1, value1, and second_finger = timeStamp2, joint_uri2, unit2, value2?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-26**:
first_finger_value has type brics_actuator/JointValue. So does second_finger_value. Then you can set the timeStamp, joint_uri, unit (optional) and value inside it. Then use the method push_back exactly as described above. push_back is a method on an STL container. Please google for it.

**Comment by [clarkeaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19625/clarkeaa/) on 2014-07-28**:
Thank you, this makes sense.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-28**:
Does it work?

**Comment by [clarkeaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19625/clarkeaa/) on 2014-07-29**:
It does not work, but I think it is because there is no action server defined for gripper control. The youbot driver has a built in arm trajectory action but not gripper control. I don't think I can use action servers with gripper control unfortunately...

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-29**:
But you should be able to get the arm/fingers to move by publishing on a topic.

**Comment by [clarkeaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19625/clarkeaa/) on 2014-07-29**:
Should I publish the goal directly onto the topic "arm_1/gripper_controller/position_command?"

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-29**:
That is how you have done it using rostopic pub. It is the same thing. :-)